# django admin site foreign key fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools

Can we have foreign key model fields display in another model as fields (not list display) on django admin site. I have a product and price model which has foreignkey of Price. I would like to display price, sale_price and sale as editable fields in both Product and Variation model.

```
class Price(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    sale = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price =  models.ForeignKey('Price')

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    price =  models.ForeignKey('Price')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the the admin inline.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: This does not work since the foreign key relationship is reverse i.e. it is not in Price model but Product Model

Comment: @Judy inlines **are** for reverse relationships

Comment: @Marcio not the exact I was looking for but I worked around it. created readonly fields on Product and Variation Model.